# Login Form in laravel

Tags: forms, laravel

i want the user to login by username or email i have a problem there i let the user login with email only i want him to insert either username or email

```
<h2>Login</h2>
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>
            {{ $error }}
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'handlelogin')) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('email/Username') !!}
    {!! Form::text('email',null,array('class' => 'form-control')) !!} 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('password') !!}
    {!! Form::password('password',array('class' => 'form-control')) !!} 
</div>
{!! Form::token() !!}
{!! Form::submit('Login',array('class' => 'btn-default')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the credentials function in your login controller and check if the value entered is an email

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = ['password' => $request->password];

    $data = $request->email;

    if(isEmail($data)) {
        $credentials['email'] = $data;
    } else {
        $credentials['username'] = $data;
    }

    return $credentials;
}
```

Check if it is an email

`function isEmail($data) {
    return filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}`

**Update: just add the following to your controller**

```
public function handlelogin(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);

    $data = ['password' => $request->get('password')];

    $email = $request->get('email');

    if($this->isEmail($email)) {
        $data['email'] = $email;
    } else {
        $data['username'] = $email;
    }

    if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
        return redirect()->intended('home');
    }

    return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email'=>'Username or Password is wrong']);
}

// check if value is an email
protected function isEmail($value) {
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Comment: public function handlelogin(Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request,User::$login_validation_rules);
     $data=$request->only('email','password');
     
     if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
     
      return redirect()->intended('home');
     }
     return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email'=>'Username or Password is wrong']);
    }

Comment: this is my controller login function

Comment: in this view i wont change anythings?

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'handlelogin')) !!}

 <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('email/Username') !!}
  {!! Form::text('email',null,array('class' => 'form-control')) !!} 

 </div>

Comment: since $request->get('email'); is still being used

Comment: i added this function it log in with email but when i entered the username no action

Comment: sorry, there was a typo. Change $credentials to $data. I have also updated the answer.

Comment: No Change :( the same login with email but username no action

Comment: remember you are to remove your previous handlelogin function first.

Comment: i did but the same :S

Comment: add `dd($data);` before if(Auth::attempt()), let's see if its getting there

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "password" => "dorg"
  "email" => "geoalbert123@gmail.com"
]

Comment: enter a username and see if you will get "username" => "[Entered Username]"

Comment: nothing happened open login page again with no action

Comment: let me see your static $login_validation_rules

Comment: public static $login_validation_rules = [

        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];

Comment: i did this and also no change and also remove require logged in with email but username no action.
        'username'      => 'required|unique:users',
        'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required'

Comment: hmm that explains it. It didn't pass the email validation and was redirecting you back to the login form.

Use this instead ` $login_validation_rules = [ 'email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required' ];`

Comment: cool. I'm also guessing you are not displaying the validation errors on the login page yet, that is why you have not been seeing the errors.

Then remember to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: yes i do all the functions but no message appear in the page i do not know why?!

Comment: do u have any suggest?!

Comment: <h2>Login</h2>
 @if(count($errors))
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <ul>
   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
   <li>
    {{ $error }}
   </li>
   @endforeach
  </ul>
 </div>

Comment: this is in the login view

Comment: this function in the controller : public function handlelogin(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);

    $data = ['password' => $request->get('password')];

    $email = $request->get('email');

    if($this->isEmail($email))
     {
        $data['email'] = $email;
     } 
     else
     {
        $data['name'] = $email;
     }

   // dd($data);
    if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
        return redirect()->intended('home');
    }

    return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email'=>'Username or Password is wrong']);
}

Comment: in user.php : public static $login_validation_rules =
     [
      'email' => 'required', 
      'password' => 'required' 
      ];